# Pandas explode and split function not working for multiple column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an dataframe like this:

```
product_title  variation type        product_price            attribute
Chauvet DJ     ['Black', 'White']    ['899.99', '949.99']    ['<p>apple,banana<p>','<p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>']
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this:

```
product_title  variation type        product_price            attribute
Chauvet DJ     Black                  899.99               <p>apple,banana<p>
Chauvet DJ     White                  949.99               <p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>
```

I tried this:

```
    df["variation type"] = df["variation type"].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'","").str.split(',')
    df["product_price"] = df["product_price"].astype(str).str.strip('[]').astype(str).str.replace("'","").astype(str).str.split(',')
    df["attribute"] = df["attribute"].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'","").str.split(',')
    data = data.explode('variation type')
    data = data.explode('product_price')
    data = data.explode('attribute')
```

getting this result which is unexpected:

```
product_title   variation type  product_price   attribute
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   899.99  <p>apple
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   899.99  banana<p>
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   899.99  <p>yewllow
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   899.99  orange
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   899.99  blue</p>
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   949.99  <p>apple
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   949.99  banana<p>
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   949.99  <p>yewllow
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   949.99  orange
0   Chauvet DJ  Black   949.99  blue</p>
0   Chauvet DJ  White   899.99  <p>apple
0   Chauvet DJ  White   899.99  banana<p>
0   Chauvet DJ  White   899.99  <p>yewllow
0   Chauvet DJ  White   899.99  orange
0   Chauvet DJ  White   899.99  blue</p>
0   Chauvet DJ  White   949.99  <p>apple
0   Chauvet DJ  White   949.99  banana<p>
0   Chauvet DJ  White   949.99  <p>yewllow
0   Chauvet DJ  White   949.99  orange
0   Chauvet DJ  White   949.99  blue</p>
```

instead of getting **only two  row** I am getting multiple rows.

Comment: just do `df.explode(['variation type', 'product_price', 'attribute'])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `explode` multiple times, you must call it only once.

Change this:

```
data = data.explode('variation type')
data = data.explode('product_price')
data = data.explode('attribute')
```

to this:

```
data = data.explode(['variation type', 'product_price', 'attribute'])
```

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of the underlying logic.

Comment: ichardec Thanks for your answer.  I tried your code but still now getting this error `columns must have matching element counts` I think this error happening for  `attribute` column

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I tried his answer but getting this error `columns must have matching element counts` this error occurring for  `attribute` column.   I have list in my attribute column like this `['<p>apple,banana<p>','<p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>']` where I have same number of item but as I use split function so it's splitting element inside in my inverted comma